# Write a method to sort any parameterized type of Set and return a TreeSet

Tags: java, sorting, set, treeset

How Can I create an implementation in which given a Set of any parameterized type, can sort it and return a TreeSet with the sorted items.

This is what I tried so far. It only works for String and Integer types though I am trying to work on any type. So the code below is my implementation. I am getting an error in the addAll method because it is expecting a Collection as its argument

```
public class SortingSets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("C");
        set.add("B");
        set.add("G");
        set.add("R");
        set.add("A");
        set.add("D");
        set.add("L");

        Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
        intSet.add(5);
        intSet.add(4);
        intSet.add(2);
        intSet.add(7);
        intSet.add(22);
        intSet.add(92);
        intSet.add(9);
        intSet.add(3);
        intSet.add(10);

        printSet(set);
        System.out.println();
        printSet(intSet);

        System.out.println("printing the set in sorted order");
        Set<? extends Object> treeSet = constructTreeSet(set);

        printSet(treeSet);  
    }

    private static Set<? extends Object> constructTreeSet(Set<? extends Object> set) {

        Set<? extends Object> resultSet;
        for(Object o : set) {
            if (o instanceof String) {
                resultSet = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }

                });
                resultSet.addAll(set);

            } else {
                resultSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }

                });
            }
        }
        return new TreeSet<Object>();
    }

    private static void printSet(Set<?> set) {
        for(Object i : set) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> TreeSet<T> toSortedSet(Set<T> set)`

Comment: *"sort **any** parameterized type of Set"* If the type is `Comparable`, then a natural order is available to sort by, and you don't need to do anything special. However, if the type is not implementing `Comparable`, what should the sort order be? The question is incompletely defined. --- Hint: Both `String` and `Integer` implements `Comparable`, so you didn't need to create those anonymous `Comparator` classes.

Comment: Thank you Boris. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

My updated and working implementation is as below

```
public class SortingSets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("C");
        set.add("B");
        set.add("G");
        set.add("R");
        set.add("A");
        set.add("D");
        set.add("L");

        Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
        intSet.add(5);
        intSet.add(4);
        intSet.add(2);
        intSet.add(7);
        intSet.add(22);
        intSet.add(92);
        intSet.add(9);
        intSet.add(3);
        intSet.add(10);

        printSet(set);
        System.out.println();
        printSet(intSet);


        System.out.println("printing the set in sorted order");
        Set<?> treeSet = constructTreeSet(intSet);

        printSet(treeSet);

    }

    private static <T extends Object & Comparable<T>> Set<T> constructTreeSet(Set<T> set) {

        Set<T> treeSet = new TreeSet<T>(new Comparator<T>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }

        });
        treeSet.addAll(set);
        return treeSet;
    }

    private static void printSet(Set<?> set) {
        for(Object i : set) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }




}
```

Thanks Boris the Spider for the hint

Comment: You can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, or even just pass the input directly to the ctor of `TreeSet` as you've required the input `Set` to be of `Comparable`.